# Setting "Default value or binding" Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I need to set the sql server columns "default value or binding" OnModelCreating (or as an property attribute) in EF code first. The reason is that I want to use sql 2012 sequence instead of autogenerated identity.

To use a sequence in sql 2012 i need to achive this:

[image: SQL 2012 sequence]

How can this be done with entity framework 4.3 Code first?

Comment: I have provided the answer here using a custom attribute: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554050/entity-framework-6-code-first-default-value/34894274#34894274

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this isn't supported yet for entity framework CodeFirst so default value can be set only with the help of XML mapping (EDMX).

You can vote here for new features:
http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2541076-allow-using-sql-server-2012-sequence-for-generatin

As much as i know FluentAPI enables you to use `DatabaseGeneratedOption` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.databasegeneratedoption(v=vs.103).aspx

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)  
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>().Property(p => p.YourColumn)  
          .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity) //None,Identity,Computed

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but may help someone looking for this answer in EF 6.
You can accomplish this using migrations:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AlterColumn("dbo.table_name", "FieldName", c => c.Guid(defaultValueSql: "YOU_SQL_FUNCTION_HERE", nullable: false));
}
```